# QuickSort with JavaParallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I need to know how to parallelize the following code of the `quickSort sorting algorithm`, using `JavaParallel`, or that I recommend some hot spots of the algortimo to parallelize it

```
public void quickSort (ArrayList<ParElementoValor> paresValores, int begin, int end){

    if (begin < end) {

            int partitionIndex = partition(paresValores, begin, end);
            quickSort(paresValores, begin, partitionIndex-1);
            quickSort(paresValores, partitionIndex+1, end);
                      }  
    }

private int partition(ArrayList<ParElementoValor> paresValores, int begin, int end) {
        ParElementoValor pivot = paresValores.get(end);

        int i = (begin-1);

        for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
            if (paresValores.get(j).getSuma() > pivot.getSuma()) {
                i++;

                ParElementoValor swapTemp = paresValores.get(i);
                paresValores.set(i, paresValores.get(j));
                paresValores.set(j, swapTemp);

                                                                  }
                                           }

        ParElementoValor swapTemp = paresValores.get(i+1);
         paresValores.set(i+1, paresValores.get(end));
         paresValores.set(end, swapTemp);

        return i+1;
    }
```

Comment: btw, It is `ParallelJava` not `JavaParallel`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ForkJoinPool` which exactly matches this kind of problems

There are plenty of examples, e.g.

https://gist.github.com/EliaRohana/25b924048d990c5358313d18daf8f491

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Thread_How_to/Concurrent/Do_quick_sort_with_ForkJoinPool_and_RecursiveAction.htm

Comment: The technology that I must use is JavaParallel

Comment: What is `JavaParallel`? Can you give a link?

Comment: I think you shoud start at https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ark/pj/doc/edu/rit/pj/ParallelSection.html

`ParallelTeam` is thread pool, `ParallelSection` is piece of work to be executed concurrently